# Google BigQuery: Pinning projects/datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I thought I could pin projects to my GCP BigQuery Classic UI, 
and then see them as pinned projects in the new UI, but today the PIN icon is no longer showing up next to a project/dataset which I have access to (in old UI), even though I can see the project.

I thought the best way to see pinned projects/datasets in the new UI was as
follows.

1. in the classic UI, click down "carrot" icon next to the current project, choose "switch to project," then choose display project
2. type in the project, choose "display project in the navigation panel."
3. click on the pin icon
4. navigate to the new console, and see the project

I thought I was doing this as recently as the mid-last week; I could be crazy though.  Today when I do these steps, there is no pin icon, so either I'm doing this incorrectly, or something has changed, please advise.

p.s.  the ultimate goal is merely pinning a project/dataset onto my console (new BigQuery UI) navigation tree - so if you have a better set of steps, please let me know.

Thanks...Rich

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read that you wanted to pin it in the new UI. I just tried and pinning works in the new UI. [image]

If you click on the "PIN A PROJECT", you need to choose your project and click OK. A pin appears next to the project you pinned.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to pin a project / dataset from a project that is not in my primary billing account.  It's been shared with me, I can query it and I can add it to the old UI, just can't pin it in the new one, and I thought in the old UI I could pin it and then it'd show up in the new UI.

Comment: Yes you are right that if you pin it in the old one, it doesn't appear in the new one. I just went ahead and did it again in the new UI as mentioned in the post above.